# Oracle varchar2 to date conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table in oracle database which has one column of type `varchar2` and it stores date. the problem is it store date in 2 character year format like 19/08/66 which is equivalent to the 19/08/1966. But when i convert this date using `to_date` function, it returns 19/08/2066 but expecting 19/08/1966. how can i convert it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_date function.

```
TO_DATE('16/06/66','DD/MM/RRRR')
```

Output is
    16/06/1966

```
TO_DATE('16/06/16','DD/MM/RRRR')
```

Output is
   16/06/2016

`TO_DATE('16/06/16','DD/MM/RRRR')` when u have run this query in 1940s

Output is 
   16/06/1916

The logic Oracle follows as below the function accepts a 2-digit year and returns a 4-digit year.
A value between 0-49 will return a 20xx year.
A value between 50-99 will return a 19xx year.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember Oracle correct the `to_date`function accepts a format_mask and if you use this mask: `'DD/MM/RRRR'` values between 0-49 will return a 20xx year and values between 50-99 will return a 19xx year. So try this:

```
to_date('19/08/66', 'DD/MM/RRRR')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with t as(
  select '16/06/66' str from dual
)
select to_date(str, 'DD/MM/YY') after, to_date(str, 'DD/MM/RR') before
  from t

AFTER       BEFORE
----------------------
06/16/2066  06/16/1966
```

Comment: Thank you zaratustra. But i have one question wouldn't it conflict when we will retrieve original date that might be equivalent to the  06/16/2066?

Comment: How can 19/08/66 be 19/08/1966 (as in the question) but also 19/08/2066? It can't. You cannot have it both ways; or, you have missed providing a substantial amount of detail in the question. If you ALSO have `06/16/2066` stored literally like that, then you could deal with such variances using a case expression.

Comment: @LalitChattar what conflict? Add this condition to your question.